# Pound Symbol # is being detected as missing link error

Tags: wordpress

The website I'm working on is using Pound Symbol # on custom links for the menu. It is detected as missing link error when ran in Integrity. What should I do to avoid this error? I'm quite new to dev so I really would appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: Could you post some of your code? I assume you mean you're using [Integrity](http://peacockmedia.software/mac/integrity/) for Mac to check broken links.

Comment: Are they anchor links? or just #links? Please share some code.

Comment: @MichaelMcGinnis yes, mac integrity
For this code, it is on a scroll down button on a divi builder
<a href="#">
<span class="scroll-down et-pb-icon">3</span></a>

Comment: @omukiguy 
This is the code and it is linked to a scroll down icon of divi builder.
<a href="#"> <span class="scroll-down et-pb-icon">3</span></a>

I had this problem and I added this code which I got from a different FAQ thread but it doesn't seem to work on the scroll down icon.
"http://a%20href=#%20onclick=doSomething();return%20false;click/a"

Comment: Is Integrity checking a live site? Are the links broken when you click on them? Then this might be a bug with Integrity. On the other hand, it's best to use real URLs as link targets instead of pound/hash symbols: https://stackoverflow.com/a/134957/1584531

Comment: I haven't really used Integrity because I use windows. My boss is running the scan. Anyways, thank you for the response. I decided to avoid using the "#" sign.